# How to allow for passing in / out an object with any keys in Flow?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I have a function like so:

```
// @flow

const myFunc = (a, b) => {
  // magic
  return c;
}
```

I want to add Flow types to this, however I'm unsure as to how I'd specify the typing.

The function takes in two arguments `a` and `b`, both of which are objects, and returns `c`, which is another object. There is no restriction on the properties that could be in either `a`, `b` or `c`.

How should I type this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `{[string]: any}` or `{[string]: *}` probably

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object` to type arguments and return type:

```
type FuncType = (a: Object, b: Object) => Object;
```

Or even shorter:

```
type FuncType = (Object, Object) => Object;
```

Then you can type the function:

```
const myFunc: FuncType = (a, b) => {
  // implementation
}
```

You can also put the typing inline, but I find it less readable in this case:

```
const myFunc: (Object, Object) => Object = (a, b) => {
  return {}
}
```